# Gravity and Collision of two continuous mass distributions

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics

How could one explain the collision of two continuous mass distributions in view of

gravitation (Newtonanian and General relativity) ?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want explained about the collision?

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: I have asked in a cooment on Jerry Schrimer's answer.

Comment: I think you are all going too far with this black hole thing, my opinion is that he is just asking the different between the scattering of point-like particles and the scattering of spheres; this can be treated due to gravitational or electrostatic interactions (if the spheres are charged). No big deal with GR. Unless the question is very very strange ...

Comment: @Cedric H.: What do you think a black hole is ? a discontinuity in a mass distribution ?

Comment: @Rajesh: At first your question was not clear at all... I interpreted by "point mass" a geometrical point affected with a mass. A classical scattering problem like the one of a charged point-like particle.

Comment: So maybe the scenario you're asking about is something like two galaxies -- no gas, just stars -- colliding. They more or less pass through each other -- google the Bullet Cluster. The attraction will behave like $1/r^2$ force when they're separated, and be much weaker while they're passing through each other, if the point masses aren't dense enough to approach another point mass closely. If the point masses were dense enough so most stars would approach another one closely, then things would get much more complicated.

Comment: When galaxies, as examples of distributed (approximated well by continuous) mass distributions get close, all sorts of very interesting tidal effects start to take place, smearing out the galaxies, requiring complex computer simulations.  If you really mean collide, then you need to think about whether non gravitational scattering of the infinitesimal mass elements also takes place, e.g. hitting a ball with a bat means electromagnetic scattering.  If you really mean only gravity is involved then Peter Shor's explanation is most realistic, since the point masses themselves miss each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of classical mechanics, your question is probably ill-formed.

Since point masses have no physical extent, the gravitational force increases without bound as `r` approached zero, which it will indeed do because they'll only collide when they're superposed.

Infinite force on a finite mass implies infinite acceleration (F = ma) which implies infinite velocity, which is inconsistent with special relativity.

Answer (score 0):

In General Relativity, a point mass is a black hole.  The collision of two black holes is a very complicated problem that has to be solved using numeric supercomputer simulation.  The short story is that they end up coalescing to a single black hole.

There are some complications from this answer that could arise from spin-orbit coupling, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Ok....i did'nt know that point masses are black holes. I was thinking that any system of particles as a system composed of point masses. Looks like in mechanics it seem to be a continuous distribution of mass. My question is what happens when two sperical distributions of mass collide ? Will they ? Even befor that how would a spherical(any shape) distribution of mass exist in view of gravity ?

Comment: depending on your answer i would want to ask more questions.